# Proof that a specific bounded sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{2^n}-3a_n)=0$$

Prove that $(a_n)$ converges and determine the limit.

I haven't got a clue of what to do here. I've been told I could watch accumulation points of the sequence but honestly I don't understand how I should proceed. Any kind of hint would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @juniven Oh I see, thanks a lot, yes that is what I meant! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $L$ is a limit point then $3L$ is also a limit point. Since sequence is bounded $L=0$. Thus sequence converges to $0$.

Comment: I see! that makes sense, but (I hope this isn't a too dumb question) how am I to know/prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded by 0? I can directly conclude that from the limit I've been given or?

Comment: @DomoB: question is not dumb at all! Use recursion. If 3L is limit point then 9L is also limit point and so $3^{n}L$ is also a limit point. If $L\neq0$ then this diverges to infinity.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So basically my proof says that L has to be 0, for the sequence to converge,because otherwise it would have more than one accumulation point in which case it doesn't converge? Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: I think, but I'm not $100\%$ sure if it is valid: since $(a_n)$ is bounded, then $\exists a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ s. t. $a_n\in(a,b)\space\forall n\in\Bbb N$ and we don't encounter the situation $\infty-\infty$,  which is an indeterminate form, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{2^n}=\alpha\space\& \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3a_n=3\beta, \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ and we might write $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{2^n}=3\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$, which could visualize what (already mentioned) is going on . –

Answer (score 0):

Hint (for the limit value):

Assume $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=s$, plug this into
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{2^n}-3a_n)=0$$
and solve for $s$.